# Angular2 System.js can't find jspm packages

Tags: javascript, angular, jspm

I'm trying to write a simple Angular2 (using Alpha 47) app and I am trying to install "npm guid" from jspm. It installs fine but when I try and run the app I always get "GET http://localhost:3001/jspm_packages/npm/guid@0.0.12 404 (Not Found)". I've also tried to load other packages as well and they also come up with a 404. Otherwise my angular2 app works fine. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

System.js config file

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  transpiler: "none",
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "defaultExtension": "js"
    }
  },

  map: {
    "guid": "npm:guid@0.0.12"
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Office Contacts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/foundation.css">
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
    <script>
        System.import('app/release/bootstrap');
    </script>

    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

My bootstrap.ts file

```
//
// ANGULAR PROVIDERS
//
import {bootstrap, provide, FORM_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ContactsService} from './contacts.service';
import {guid} from 'guid';

//
// APP COMPONENT
// Top level component that holds all of our components
//
import {App} from './app';


//
// BOOTSTRAP
// Bootstrap our app with the top level component and
// inject services and providers
//
bootstrap(App, [
    FORM_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ContactsService,
    guid,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you only added `"defaultExtension": "js"` for `app`

something is wrong with the extension, have you tried to copy the link into your browser `http://localhost:3001/jspm_packages/npm/guid@0.0.12`, and then add `.js` to see if it loads.

try this

```
 System.config({
  map: { npm: 'jspm_packages/npm/' },
  packages: {
    npm: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back with you :-) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Alpha 53?  If so:
They got rid of 'angular2/angular2'.  You have to import now using 'angular2/bootstrap', 'angular2/core'.

I'm actually having a potentially similar issue where 'angular2/bootstrap' isn't importing properly into SystemJS.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks for responding! I was having so many problems with Alpha53 that I decided to go down to Alpha 47. Everything was fine until I needed to load external dependencies :-/

Comment: I have an 'almost' working starter for alpha53.  Feel free to try and use that. https://github.com/jyana/Angular2-TypeScript

The only issue is that I'm importing directly when I import {bootstrap} .  You'll see that in my app.ts file.  It does work though if you do it that way.  There seems to be some issue with SystemJS.  Trying to figure that out still myself.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for the response and I'll check out your code for alpha 53. :-) But what I am really looking for currently is how to get system.js to find the jspm packages that are loaded :-/ Thanks again though!